# Mongodb - Retrieving entry where dates in array does not overlap with given dates

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a MongoDB Documents User that contains an array that looks like this:

```
"meeting" : [ 
    {
        "start" : ISODate("2018-04-17T12:00:00.000Z"),
        "end" : ISODate("2018-04-17T13:00:00.000Z")
    }, 
    {
        "start" : ISODate("2018-04-17T20:00:00.000Z"),
        "end" : ISODate("2018-04-17T22:00:00.000Z")
    }
]
```

And I want to retrieve, given two date as:

```
date1 = 2018-04-17T12:00:00.000Z
date2 = 2018-04-17T15:00:00.000Z
```

every Users that does not have at least on date that overlap the two other (every available user between date1 and date2). Which means:

1. start can't be in [date1; date2[
2. end can't be in ]date1; date2]
3. and we can not have start < date1 && end > date2

I've tried many things and looked up many topics but didn't manage to get this work properly... Here is what I tried:

```
User.find({role: 'coach', $nor: [ {$and: [{"meeting.start": {$gte: date1}},{"meeting.start": {$lt: date2}}]},{$and: [{"meeting.end": {$gt: date1}},{"meeting.end": {$lte: date2}}]}],
        $or: [ {training: []},{"meeting.start": {$gte: date1}}, {"meeting.end": {$lte: date2}}]}, function(err, coaches){ [...]
```

It works except if a user have a meeting from 10 to 11 and another from 15 to 16 and I tried to find available user from 12 to 13, this user will not be retrieved.

**What did I get wrong?**

Comment: Maybe you need to use the $elmentMatch (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/). The $nor condition will return every user that are failing the condition, so if the "12 to 13 query" doesn't retrieve any user it means that the $nor conditions is not failing.

Comment: @thejoin But I want that neither meeting.start be in [date1; date2[ and neither that meeting.end be in [date1; date2] ! This first $nor is to exclude the start or end overlap with date1 and date2. The last part of my request I try to get rid of the User that have a meeting where date1 and date2 are included in an meeting.